# Are there any VMware ESXi virtual memory limits?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

When using vSphere 6.0 Enterprise Plus Edition, are there any memory limits (virtual RAM per virtual machine)? I am refering to the vRAM entitlements.

Comment: Yes, there is. The VMware documentation lists all of the VM limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

limits are available in [pdf](https://www.vmware.com/pdf/vsphere6/r60/vsphere-60-configuration-maximums.pdf) for vSphere 6.0. Maximum of RAM per VM is 4TB, but as comment says

> The actual value supported is 4080 GB and not 4096 GB.

Comment: My question is about vRAM entitlements, not RAM.

Comment: They don't have consistent term ussage, but result is the same:  Virtual
machines will support up to 128 virtual CPUs (vCPUs) and 4TB
virtual RAM (vRAM).

Comment: and if you mean vRAM from licencing perspective, this model was abandoned in 5.1 version